# Multiplying Pixel Values in BufferedImage results in strange Behaviour

Tags: java, byte, bufferedimage, multiplication, artifacts

I am currently working on a program to help photographers with the creation of timelapses.
It calculates an decline or rise in brightness over a series of images. So the change in Exposure and iso for example dont affect the overall decline in brightness.

For this i use a simple Swing-based Interface which displays the first and last image. Under them are sliders to adjust the Brightness of the image.

This is applied via a direct manipulation of the BufferedImages underlying DataBuffer.

Mostly this works but i encountered some images which seem to have kind of a problem.

Do you have an idea why this is happening?

```
public BufferedImage getImage(float mult){
    BufferedImage retim;
    retim =  new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
    Graphics g = retim.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    DataBufferByte db = (DataBufferByte) retim.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    byte[] bts = db.getData();
    for(int i=0;i<bts.length;i++){
        float n = bts[i]*mult;
        if(n > 255){
            bts[i]= (byte) 255;
        }else{
            bts[i] = (byte) n;
        }
    }
    return retim;
}
```

This is the method which takes an float and multiplies every pixel in the image with it. (And some code to prevent the byte values from overflowing).

[This is the unwanted behaviour (on the left) and the expected on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osZfp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line, and it occurs due to the fact that Java `byte`s are signed (in the range [-128...127]):

```
float n = bts[i] * mult;
```

After the multiplication, your `n` variable may be negative, thus causing the overflow to occur.

To fix it, use a bit mask to get the value as an unsigned integer (in the range [0...255]), before multiplying with the constant:

```
float n = (bts[i] & 0xff) * mult;
```

---

A better fix yet, is probably to use the [`RescaleOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html), which is built to do brightness adjustments on `BufferedImage`s.

Something like:

```
public BufferedImage getImage(float mult) {
    return new RescaleOp(mult, 0, null).filter(img, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried implementing a pseudo unsigned version of the java byte to overcome this but simply using the rescale op works a lot better ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the capping of the value in certain bytes in the image.

For example (assuming RGB simple colour space):

The pixel starts at (125,255,0), if you multiply by factor 2.0, the result is (255,255,0). This is a different hue than the original.

This is also why the strange results only occur on pixels that already have high brightness to start with.

This [link](http://www.kweii.com/site/color_theory/2007_LV/BrightnessCalculation.pdf) may help with better algorithm for adjusting brightness.

You could also refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939520/formula-for-adjusting-brightness-contrast-on-canvas).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The paper you pointed to seems to be no longer available but i managed to find it via the waybackmachine. Although it seems as the method proposed in this paper is something i already do, namely multiplying pixel values.